# How to write data in to Xml File Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to create a XML file dynamically. After creating the file, I want to create a following structure in XML file by coding in **c#** windows phone.

```
<Contacts> 
   <Contact>
       <Name>ABC</Name>
       <PhoneNumber>1234</PhoneNumber>
       <Email>abc@abc.com</Email>
   </Contact>
</Contacts>
```

I want to insert these type of data in XML file. I have searched on it and I found this example [add data to existing xml file using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783525/add-data-to-existing-xml-file-using-linq). 
But I am not able to access **XDocument** in my windows phone project. I have also added **System.XML** assembly.

So, How can I insert data in XML file? Is it possible in windows phone?

Comment: You should be able to access the LINQ to XML (`XDocument`) in the WP project. Did you include `System.Xml.Linq` namespace?

Comment: Possible duplicate of -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386962/how-to-save-data-in-xml-file-in-windows-phone-7

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek Thanks for reply. After including the Sys.Xml.Linq, I am able to access XDocument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XDocument is in System.Xml.Linq namespace. So, at the top of your code file, add:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Then you can write the data to your file the following way:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
var contactsElement = new XElement("Contacts", 
                             new XElement("Contact",
                                  new XElement("Name", "ABC"),
                                  new XElement("PhoneNumber", "1234"),
                                  new XElement("Email", "abc@abc.com")));
 xDoc.Add(contactsElement);
 xDoc.Save(...);
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for reply. What should I write in xDoc.Save() method?

Comment: For example: `var fileStream = File.OpenWrite("file.xml");`
            `xDoc.Save(fileStream);`

Comment: I am trying to create a xml file dynamically, but I am not able to create it. Is there any example?

Comment: Can you please give any example? or any Link

Comment: `var file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();`


`var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("file.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, file);` you will find plenty of examples in the web, starting from SO.